# How to synchronize modifying and showing html with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, synchronize

My code below does not work. I want to remove certain parts of the loaded page. The page should NOT be shown in the dialog before all modifications took place.

```
  var $div = $('<div>');
       $div.load("../payment/list", function(){
           $div.find("#cssmenu").remove();
           $div.find("#toolbar").remove();
           $div.find("#categoryDialog").remove();              
           $div.find("h1").remove();  

           $("#paymentDialog2").html($div);
       });
```

But the content is loaded and modified afterwards, which looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try try using ajax() instead:

```
var $div = $('<div>');
var response;

$.ajax({
  url: "../payment/list"
}).done(function( data ) {
  response = data;
});

// remove unwanted elements
$div.find("#cssmenu").remove();
$div.find("#toolbar").remove();
$div.find("#categoryDialog").remove();              
$div.find("h1").remove(); 

// append data from ajax response to your container
$div.append(response); 

// display you content
$("#paymentDialog2").html($div);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use jquery ajax get

```
$.get( "../payment/list", function( data ) {
    var $div = $('<div>');
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find("#cssmenu").remove();
    $data.find("#toolbar").remove();
    $data.find("#categoryDialog").remove();              
    $data.find("h1").remove();  

    $div.html($data.html());
    $("#paymentDialog2").html($div);
});
```

Comment: I tried this. For some reason, the removing does not work with that: $.get( "../payment/list", function( data ) {          
          var $tmp = $(data);
          $tmp.find("#cssmenu").remove();
          $tmp.find("#toolbar").remove();
          $tmp.find("#categoryDialog").remove();              
          $tmp.find("h1").remove();  
          
          
          $("#paymentDialog2").html($tmp);
      });

Comment: Here is a working [plnker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rsW9vrFMfvTuJ77tQK3u?p=preview) example

Comment: Make sure that the payment list returned html data is wrapped in root element like in the plnker example let say a Div element

Comment: Your sample works perfect. On my page, which is more "heavy" it doesn't. I believe, the html is shown in the dialog, before the remove commands have been executed. So I need to make sure, that every remove command is executed synchronously..

Comment: I believe the find and remove functions are really synchronous.

Comment: make sure you're using a valid HTML element IDs, id should begin with a letter

Answer (score 0):

The reason is load() function loads the content and after that executes the the call back function.Simplest way to solve the problem is by using css. Make a parent div to the response and make it hidden.And set it visible after attaching it to the page element.

let ../payment/list be like

```
<div id="parent" style="display:none">
<!-- your page content -->

</div>
```

then

```
    var $div = $('<div>');
           $div.load("../payment/list", function(){
               $div.find("#cssmenu").remove();
               $div.find("#toolbar").remove();
               $div.find("#categoryDialog").remove();              
               $div.find("h1").remove();  

               $("#paymentDialog2").html($div);
               $div.find("#parent").removeAttr("style");

           });
```